# Ubuntu 13.04 Bootable USB Drive- Desktop not responding

Tags: usb, 13.04

I have a bootable USB drive that works just fine everywhere but the desktop. The desktop does not show icons or give me the ability to right-click. Everything works great except for the desktop. I haven't seen another post on this, so I hope I am not posting a question already answered. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please tell me if you find anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Not complete answer posted as comment 19 May 2013**
Have the issue as well and did think it strange. Not until reading this realised icons for "install Ubuntu" is missing as well as no right click options on desktop. Have not got an answer but searching Ask Ubuntu does go towards confirming this is a bug. Look at these Ask Ubuntu search results for to start searching for pointers/answers. Maybe searching Launchpad may show others are experiencing the same and may have workarounds or solutions that have not been posted here or Ubuntu Forums yet.

**Conclusion posted 11 August 2013**
Did acknowledge i would be back and doing a clean up found your unanswered question and request in comment. "A promise made is a debt unpaid"
Can confirm the highly unusual symptoms described in question only happened from live session when trying Ubuntu 13.04. On installing Ubuntu (which i was a bit dubious of doing but was very surprised at results) and then updating and upgrading 13.04 has run for me very nearly flawlessy and very responsive due to using highest system specs i have had liberty of using on PC. Looking forward to 13.10 already... Ubuntu 13.04 is definitely the most polished release from Ubuntu so far.